# a valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found happens on one project only

Tags: ios, xcode

When I tried to run my application on a device, I got "a valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found" error dialog. I have checked my provision file and my device UUID, everything works fine. And I checked my "Code Signing Identify", all selected 'iOS Development'. But I still got this error. Then I created a new xcode project and use the same bundle identifier, everything works fine. I think the problem happens only one that perticular project. How can I find out root case? Does anyone have any clue on that?

Comment: "Then I created a new xcode project and use the same bundle identifier, everything works fine" Excellent. So transfer your code into that new project and your problems are over.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a new CSR from keychain and using it download new development certificate from developer center. Now create a new provisional profile using this certificate for your project. Make sure you delete your previous development certificate from keychain access and add this new one.

Answer (score 0):

After tried a few times, I found the root cause. It is not related to code sign nor CSR. In fact, I am using cocoapods to manage my project dependency. Recently I imported a new library called LeanCloud which cause this issue. It seems that LeanCloud library doesn't work well with cocoapods. After remove this dependency from Podfile, everything works fine. I will figure other way to import LeanCloud framework.